# Converting nodes with the same name to text with c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, csv, nodes

I found this guide, to convert my xml file to csv: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693157.aspx

Everything was okay until a part of nodes had the same name

```
 <ProductSpecification>
                    <Property>
                      <Name>CLEANING PERFORMANCE</Name>
                      <Value>-</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                      <Name>COLOUR</Name>
                      <Value>White</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                      <Name>DIMENSIONS (H x W x D cm)</Name>
                      <Value>85 x 60 x 45</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                      <Name>DISH SETTING CAPACITY</Name>
                      <Value>-</Value>
                    </Property>
</ProductSpecification>
```

If i try using

```
(string)el.Element("ProductSpecification"),
```

My whole text combines in to one big pile of letters without any spaces between nodes:

```
CLEANING PERFORMANCE-COLOURWhiteDIMENSIONS (H x W x D cm)85 x 60 x 45DISH SETTING CAPACITY-
```

And if i try to use

```
(string)el.Element("ProductSpecification").Element("Property"),
```

i just get a error without any explanation of what's wrong

The result that i need is:

```
Cleaning Performance
-
Colour
White
```

Soo... I tried everything i could think of, but couldn't get to write the text with spaces between nodes
EDIT: ADDING MY WHOLE SCRIPT AT THE MOMENT:

```
XElement custOrd = XElement.Load("_output.xml");
            string csv =
                (from el in custOrd.Elements("PriceCatalog").Elements("ListofCatalogDetails").Elements("CatalogItem").Elements("Product").Elements("ProductSpec").Elements("ProductDetails")
                 select
         String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12},{13},{14},{15},{16}, \"{17}\"{18}",
             (string)el.Element("ProductID"),
             (string)el.Element("PartNumber"),
             (string)el.Element("Description"),
             (string)el.Element("LongDesc"),
             (string)el.Element("Manufacturer"),
             (string)el.Element("Category01"),
             (string)el.Element("Category02"),
             (string)el.Element("Category03"),
             (string)el.Element("CategoryVAT"),
             (string)el.Element("PeriodofWarranty"),
             (string)el.Element("Qty").Element("QtyAvailable"),
             (string)el.Element("UnitPrice"),
             (string)el.Element("VatRate"),
             (string)el.Element("Weight"),
             (string)el.Element("Height"),
             (string)el.Element("Width"),
             (string)el.Element("Length"),
             (string)el.Element("ProductSpecification"),
             Environment.NewLine

         )
                )
                .Aggregate(
                    new StringBuilder(),
                    (sb, s) => sb.Append(s),
                    sb => sb.ToString()
                );
            Console.WriteLine(csv);
```

EDIT02: I just found out that some items don't have "ProductSpecification" node, but c# doesn't give any errors about that, but if I use "ProductSpecification.Property" - it crashes. Now I just need to bypass this somehow

Comment: And the specific error message is?

Comment: Use "Elements("Property")" not "Element("Property")" (string)el.Element("ProductSpecification").Elements("Property")

Comment: Luc, I get this: `System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Vijai, I tried that, but it doesn't work like that, I get: `Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' to 'string'`

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the XML like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
foreach (var property in doc.Element("ProductSpecification").Elements("Property"))
{
    foreach(var element in property.Descendants())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
    }
}
```

This will yield the following:

```
CLEANING PERFORMANCE
-
COLOUR
White
DIMENSIONS (H x W x D cm)
85 x 60 x 45
DISH SETTING CAPACITY
```

Comment: I would need another loop for that, is it possible to add a line to split nodes with "_" or anything while reading the node?
I attached my whole script to my original post

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, I have not debugged it

```
XElement custOrd = XElement.Load("yourxml.xml");

string csv =
    (from el in custOrd.Element("ProductSpecification").Elements("Property")
    select
        String.Format("{0},{1}",
            (string)el.Element("Name"),
            (string)el.Element("Value"),
            Environment.NewLine
        )
    )
    .Aggregate(
        new StringBuilder(),
        (sb, s) => sb.Append(s),
        sb => sb.ToString()
    );
Console.WriteLine(csv);
```